# What are the trade-offs of using reset_session vs session[:user_id] = nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to understand what the best way to destroy a session is.  I suppose reset_session is more drastic than just clearing out the user ala session[:user_id] = nil.

But in so many examples, I've seen session[:user_id] = nil instead of reset_session.  Why?  Is there a reason I wouldn't want to completely destroy the session?

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cases where you might want the session to be inactive, but still stored somewhere. In the application I'm working on, for example, we display a list of recently active users for admins. These users' sessions are deactivated when they log out (`session[:user_id] = nil`), but we keep the sessions to see who's been active recently.

Comment: Ah, I see.  But session[:user_id] = nil us pretty effective from a security perspective?

Comment: Theoretically a hostile user could ignore your request to drop this from the cookie and remain logged in. You'd need another mechanism to reject the cookie, such as changing a login token in the database that would subsequently not match.

Comment: @tadman, I'm using active_record_store, so the change is made in the db, not in the cookie, so I don't think this is an issue. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you're saving the session in the database then the cookie is just a token to access that database record so you're okay. By default the cookie store is used that is entirely within the user's control.